# Inserting code and undoing

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am currently working on a "WYSIWYG" (What you see is what you get) HTML editor. I am making this for personal use to broaden my understanding of VB.Net. The problem I have encountered is when I use this code:

```
Dim insertText = "<h1>Example Header</h1>"
Dim insertPos As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(insertPos, insertText)
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = insertPos + insertText.Length
```

The code will work perfectly fine by adding to the text in the RichTextBox; however, if I were to make a mistake and try to call the Undo() method, nothing would happen. The Code would stay there. I assume this would be because the text was neither typed or pasted into the RichTextBox.

What I am trying to accomplish: I need a code snippet that will allow me to paste or add predefined HTML code into a RichTextBox where the cursor is (like above), and be able to Undo it as well.

Also, if it would help to know, the project uses a RichTextBox control where the user can type his/her own HTML document, and for shortcuts can click buttons to add headers, buttons,links etc to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Replacing* the Text resets the Undo/Redo stack, so best try to avoid that.

Simple work around:

```
Dim insertText As String = "<h1>Example Header</h1>"
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = insertText
```

Comment: This was the answer I needed. Thank you. I had no idea what I was doing was resetting the undo/redo stack. Very helpful answer as it solved the problem.

Comment: I also forgot to ask a simple question elaborating on your answer. I am confused as to why in the RichTextBox1.SelectedText statement, the code is added to the RichTextBox where my cursor is, regardless of there being no text already there. This IS what I wanted, I am just curious how and why it works this way. Thanks.

Comment: @user2984806 If you have no text, then the current SelectedIndex is at zero.  In this case, SelectedText is an empty string at index zero with a SelectedLength of zero.

Comment: Perfect explanation, I just could not figure it out myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RichTextBox.Selected*` properties to set text or change color etc. that can be undone.

```
Private Sub InsertTextInRTB(ByVal text As String, ByVal insertPos As Integer)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = insertPos
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = text
End Sub

Private Sub InsertTextInRTB(ByVal text As String)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = text
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
    Dim insertText = "<h1>Example Header</h1>"
    InsertTextInRTB(insertText)              '<-- to insert at current cursor position
    InsertTextInRTB(insertText, 100)         '<-- to insert at some other position
```

Comment: This was a great answer, but not exactly the answer I was looking for; however, I am sure this will be found useful for others. Thanks for sharing!